# Setting up django parallel test in setting.py

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, parallel-processing, parallel-testing

Hello I know that it's possible to run tests in django in parallel via `--parallel` flag eg. `python manage.py test --parallel 10`. It really speeds up testing in project I'm working for, what is really nice. But Developers in company shares different hardware setups. So ideally I would like to put parallel argument in `./app_name/settings.py` so every developer would use at least 4 threads in testing or number of cores provided by multiprocessing lib.

I know that I can make another script let's say `run_test.py` in which I make use of `--parallel`, but I would love to make parallel testing 'invisible'.

To sum up - my question is: Can I put number of parallel test runs in settings of django app?
And if answer is yes. There is second question - Would command line argument (X) `manage.py --parallel X` override settings from './app_name/settings'

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no setting for this, but you can override the `test` command to set a different default value. In one of your installed apps, create a `.management.commands` submodule, and add a `test.py` file. In there you need to subclass the old test command:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.commands.test import Command as TestCommand

class Command(TestCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        super().add_arguments(parser)
        if hasattr(settings, 'TEST_PARALLEL_PROCESSES'):
            parser.set_defaults(parallel=settings.TEST_PARALLEL_PROCESSES)
```

This adds a new default to the `--parallel` flag. Running `python manage.py test --parallel=1` will still override the default.

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you very much. 
Code has two little, tiny mistakes: There should be ":" in if statement and there should be 'set_defaults' instead of 'set_default'.

Thank you once more, you saved hours of testing execution time :).

Comment: @AlexBaranowski Fixed :)